# How does MongoDB Stitch host static assets?

Tags: mongodb-stitch

Customer service is not helpful so I'll ask here. The [FAQs of MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch/faq) answer the question "Can I store and serve my static web assets using MongoDB Stitch?" by saying "Yes, Stitch Hosting can be used to store and deliver all of your static web assets, including html, css, and image files."

What is Stitch Hosting? I can't find other information about this in the documentation or the dashboard. I found a separate company called Stitch Hosting who said they know nothing about that reference, so the reference must not be referring to them. I'm hoping that I can indeed host static web assets on the Stitch platform.

Comment: Static hosting isn't available on Stitch yet, but it should be in a few weeks. I'm not sure why that says it's already available. I'll link docs when it's released.

Comment: Great thanks @haley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/hosting/). Easiest way to start:

1. Navigate to Hosting in the side nav
2. Enable Hosting
3. Upload your files